# How do I check a checkbox that was added via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, document, setattribute

I want to check a checkbox that was added to the web page via JavaScript but the element is not in the `webbrowser.document`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you have a tag that shouldn't be there. `c#`

Comment: Is element suppose to be checked using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

You must bind your events on an element that exist when the binding is run. To add an event to a dynamic element, use the `.on()` functionality in javascript, like the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#selector", function(e){
  // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: I also answered this question, but mine was not as good as this answer so I deleted it. This guy's got it right.

Comment: basically I've tried to use getelementbyid but this does not find the element even after the page has loaded and the element I am looking for is not in the html source of the webpage.